# How to read swift headers

Tags: swift

When I cmd click the split function in Xcode, it takes me to the header file. This is what it reads

```
public func split(maxSplit: Int = default, allowEmptySlices: Bool = default, @noescape isSeparator: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.SubSequence]
```

How does the following implementation work with above declaration?

```
someString.characters.split { $0 == "." }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
public func split(maxSplit: Int = default, allowEmptySlices: Bool = default, @noescape isSeparator: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.SubSequence]
```

`maxSplit`: The first parameter, `maxSplit`, allows you to specify the maximum number of pieces that the sequence will be split into. The default is `Int.max`.

`allowEmptySlices`: The second parameter, `allowEmptySlices` specifies whether or not two consecutive separators in the sequence should lead to an empty slice. The default is `false`. For example if you had a String, `"A..B"`, and you split on the `.` character, you could end up with either two (`["A", "B"]`) or three (`["A", "", "B"]`) items in the output array depending on what you pass for this parameter.

`isSeparator`: The last parameter is the closure that you pass to identify where to split the sequence.

Since both `maxSplit` and `allowEmptySlices` have default arguments, you don't need to include them in your function call unless you want to change them. The only parameter that you have to supply is the `isSeparator` closure.

In your case, you called:

```
someString.characters.split { $0 == "."}
```

...which is the equivalent of:

```
someString.characters.split(maxSplit: Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false) { $0 == ".' }
```

You could also write your function call like this:

```
someString.characters.split(isSeparator: { $0 == "." })
```

The way that you have written it makes use of the "trailing closure" syntax. If a function takes a closure as it's final argument, you can move the closure *outside the parentheses* like this:

```
someString.characters.split() { $0 == "." }
```

And if the function takes *only one argument* (not counting any default arguments that you are not supplying) then you can omit the parentheses altogether:

```
someString.characters.split { $0 == "." }
```

At the highest level, what happens is that `split` iterates through the sequence of characters. It tests each character using the supplied closure, and if the closure returns `true`, it splits the sequence on that character. In your case it will split the sequence of characters every time it locates a `"."`.

Some other notes:

`rethrows`: The whole function is marked `rethrows`. It will throw an error, but only if the closure that you pass for the `isSeparator` argument throws an error itself. Note that the `isSeparator` parameter allows you to pass a closure that throws an error, but you don't have to. Any time a function accepts a closure that throws an error, it will also accept a closure that does not throw. This is because non-throwing functions are a sub-type of throwing functions.

`@noescape`: The `isSeparator` parameter is marked `@noescape`. That simply means that nothing in the closure will survive past the end of the call to `split`.

Answer (score 5):

Your line `someString.characters.split { $0 == "."}` uses the default values for `maxSplit` and `allowEmptySlices` and specifies a custom closure for `isSeparator`. *Some* longer version of calling the function `split` is:

```
let arr = str.characters.split(Int.max, allowEmptySlices: false) { (char) -> Bool in
    char == "."
}
```

Since the above code uses the same values as the actual defaults (`Int.max` and `false`) you can remove the first two parameters and since the closure is the last parameter (making it a trailing closure) you can omit the entire parameter and simply write a closure in the following way:

```
let arr = str.characters.split { (char) -> Bool in
    char == "."
}
```

Now we can simplify the closure by omitting the specific signature:

```
let arr = str.characters.split { $0 == "." }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
someString.characters.split { $0 == "."}
```

is equivalent to

```
someString.characters.split(isSeparator: { $0 == "."})
```

the closure in your code is called a [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102), closures that are the last parameter to a function can be placed after the function declaration, and if no other parameters remain, you can also omit `()`.

The first two parameters have default values, so they can be omitted, leading to the simplified call you posted.