# What is the syntax for a closure argument in swift

Tags: swift, closures

In Swift headers, the `isSeparator:` argument accepts a closure

```
public func split(maxSplit: Int = default, allowEmptySlices: Bool = default, @noescape isSeparator: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.SubSequence]
```

But in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), it lists closure syntax differently

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

How are you supposed to know that `(Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool rethrows` refers to a closure / requires a closure? Are there other ways that the headers/docs might list argument as meaning a closure?

Comment: In a header `(parameters) -> return type` **within** the parentheses of a function is always a closure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read swift headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661048/how-to-read-swift-headers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "thing" giving away that this is a closure is the `->`. The full type is

```
(Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool
```

It means that the closure takes a variable of type `Self.Generator.Element` and has to return a `Bool` upon some calculation based on the input. It may additionally throw some error while doing so - that is what the throws is for.

What you then write

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

would be *an* actual implementation, a value of some generic closure type.

The type of a closure is for example `(someInt:Int, someDouble:Double) -> String`:

```
var a : ((someInt:Int, someDouble:Double) -> String)
```

Once again the thing giving away that a is actually a closure is the `->` in the type declaration.

Then you assign something to `a` via some code snippet following your second code block:

```
a = { (integer, floating) -> String in
    return "\(integer) \(floating)"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell by the argument's type. Everything in Swift has a type, including functions and closures.

For example, this function...

```
func add(a: Int, to b: Int) -> Int { return a + b }
```

...has type `(Int, Int) -> Int`. (It takes two `Int`s as parameters, and returns an `Int`.)

And this closure...

```
let identity: Int -> Int = { $0 }
```

...has type `Int -> Int`.

Every function and closure has a type, and in the type signature there is always a `->` that separates the parameters from the return value. So anytime you see a parameter (like `isSeparator`) that has a `->` in it, you know that the parameter expects a closure.

Answer (score 2):

the `isSeparator` definition means  `(Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool` that you will be given an Element and you should return a Bool. When you will call split, you then can do the following :

```
[1,2,3].split(…, isSeparator : { element -> Bool in 
    return false 
})
```

This is a pure silly example but that illustrates the second part of your question